# Sobolev spaces defined on non-compact Lie groups

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces

In this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81274/is-there-a-generalization-of-sobolev-spaces-for-certain-locally-compact-groups#), a question was raised to discuss the generalization of Sobolev spaces on locally compact Lie groups. Now my question is whether there exists a generalization of Sobolev spaces and associated theories of the Laplace operator on noncompact Lie groups. My expectation is that the theory should be reduced to coincide with that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a trivial case of noncompact Lie groups. But I fail to find useful references on this subject. Can someone kindly help me with this difficulty? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a similar question sometime back but could not find anything in literature.. good question.